# Selecting Associated records with Rails and simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a project with partials associated with it. I am trying to create a selection box so that the user can select a parcel from the associated parcels to add to another model associated with the project. What I have below is my attempt that displays the parcels but simply returns the id ie I get

```
undefined method `each' for "64":String
```

With 64 being the parcel's ID.

I would also like to allow the user to select multiple parcels or no parcels.

```
 <% @pro_par = @project.parcels %>
 <%= f.input :parcels, :collection => @pro_par, :label_method =>:tax_parcel %>
```

How can I fixe this?

Comment: Please post the complete error log

Comment: Sorry I was unclear the selection box is in a separate model from the project so I have Project which has leases and parcels. I want a selection box in leases that just show parcels in the project ie f:association :parcels gives me all parcels I want f.association :parcels where  project_id == id

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a associated model like

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parcels
  # rest of the code
end
```

then you can directly call the associating models in the view using simple form

```
<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>
  <!-- remaining codes -->
  <%= f.association :parcels %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

it automatically lets you select multiple parcels.

Reference: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations